# Driver Wireless Network card - Acer Aspire 3000

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

IInstalled Ubuntu 14.04 a Acer Aspire 3000. It does not recognize the wireless network card. I'm new on linux. Someone can tell me where can I download. Thank you

Comment: Open terminal Ctrl+Alt+t, run `sudo lshw -c network` add output to the question (BTW, use that small [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/470762/edit) button under the question.)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem (same laptop, but Xubuntu 14.04.2) and this article solved my problem:

https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/382462